# Replace object in array in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to replace an object in an array using an index, but nothing will save. This is what the document looks like:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58a71ec0c80a9a0436ae2fb1"
    },
    "owner": "contact1@gmail.com",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "work": "",
            "home": "",
            "mobile": "",
            "email": "",
            "company": "",
            "last": "Contact",
            "middle": "",
            "first": "New"
        },
        {
            "first": "Another",
            "middle": "",
            "last": "Contact",
            "company": "",
            "email": "",
            "mobile": "",
            "home": "",
            "work": ""
        }
    ],
    "__v": 1
}
```

And this is what I've tried..

```
Contacts.findById({_id: "58a71ec0c80a9a0436ae2fb1"}, function(err,document) {
    document.contacts[req.body.indexOfObjectToBeEdited] = req.body.updatedObject
    console.log(document)
    document.save(function(err) {
        return res.json({event:"Updated Contact"})
    })
})
```

Right before document.save() I console.log(document) and it reflects the correct changes. But when I save, nothing is updated in the mongodb and I receive no errors. What should I be doing differently?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "when I print"? You mean after the save function?

Comment: Right before document.save, I will console.log(document) and it looks updated. But when I check the db after actually saving, it looks like it was never updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try inserting this line right before saving. As modifying an array require we need to manual tell the mongoose the it is modified.

```
document.markModified("contacts");
```

Check the **Usage Notes** in the documentation for more information 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Comment: Learned something new!

Comment: Thanks @Rohail Najam, you saved my sanity. I tried to update an array with a new one in every way without success, and "markModified" did the work.